# Android app make shared lib optional on other platforms

Tags: android, shared-libraries

I am including the Epson ePOSPrint and StarIO libraries in my app in order to support printing to Epson and Star POS printers connected via USB. Printing works well on both printers.

The Epson library includes a shared library `lib/armeabi/libeposprint.so`. Considering the name of the folder `armeabi`, I assume this library is for devices with ARM architecture only, and in fact installing the app on an Intel Atom based (virtual) device with Android 5.0 fails with

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS
```

On Intel Atom based devices running an Android version lower than 5.0 the installation does not fail, but I don't know what happens when trying to print.

Anyway, since the app also supports Star printers and the Star library does not depend on a native shared lib, I would like to allow installing the app even on Intel Atom based devices so that at least Star printers can be used.

Is it possible to make shared libs optional somehow so the installation won't fail? Is it a good idea at all since this would make the app partially broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make shared libs optional somehow so the installation won't fail?

The only way that I know of to do this is to have separate APKs by CPU architecture, such as Android Studio/Gradle for Android offer with the `split` mechanism.

> Is it a good idea at all since this would make the app partially broken?

That depends on what "partially broken" means.

If you mean "reduced functionality", because you use `Build` to detect what CPU you're on and gracefully degrade if you are not on a device that supports your libraries, that's reasonable.

If you mean "the app done blow'd up", that would not be good. :-)

Comment: I was thinking about "reduced functionality" but I didn't know yet how to detect the CPU architecture, so thanks for the hint on `Build`!